# Linear independence check for my textbook

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading my text:

[image]

and I'm confused... aren't $b_1, b_2, and b_3$ also linearly independent? What's a quick way to check?

I converted those column vectors into row vectors and reduced and I got:

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}

solutions are that let $v_2 = 0$ and $v_1 = 0$ and so the only solution here is the 0 vector. Isn't this linearly independent?

Comment: $b_2=b_3+2b_1$.

Comment: What did I do that was wrong? How do I check more formally?

Answer (score 1):

$b_1, b_2$ and $b_3$ are not linearly independent, because there is a non-trivial linear relation among them: $2b_1-b_2+b_3=0$. Suppose you don't know the coefficient. Then you're asking whether $$\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2+\alpha_3b_3+\alpha_4b_4=0$$ has a non-trivial solution or not. Equivalently, $$\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\alpha_2\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\alpha_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\alpha_4\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&3&1&3\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\\\alpha_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\boxed 1&0&-2&0\\0&\boxed 1&1&0\\0&0&0&\boxed 1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\\\alpha_4\end{bmatrix}=0.$$
Then you've $\alpha_3$ being free. The solution to the system is infinite: $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\\\alpha_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\alpha_3,\, \alpha_3\in\mathbb R.$$

*Recall that* you was initially asking whether the equation has a solution or not. The answer is yes. If you take $\alpha_3=1$, one particular solution to the relation $\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2+\alpha_3b_3+\alpha_4b_4=0$ would be $$2b_1+(-1)b_2+b_3=0\implies b_3=-2b_1+b_2.$$

Comment: You’ve got a sign error in your first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t really need to go through all of that since the text gives you a nontrivial linear combination of those three vectors that vanishes, namely, $2\mathbf b_1-\mathbf b_2+\mathbf b_3=0$, which you can verify for yourself.

That aside, you’ve misinterpreted the result of your row-reduction. There are two nonzero rows in the RREF, which means that the span of the three vectors is only two-dimensional. By definition, *every* set of three elements of that space is linearly dependent.

Moreover, that matrix doesn’t correspond to the equation $c_1\mathbf b_1+c_2\mathbf b_2+c_3\mathbf b_3=0$. That equation is represented by the *transpose* of the matrix that you row-reduced. Your matrix corresponds to the system $\mathbf b_i\cdot\mathbf v_i=0$, which is rather different (ans which, by the way, also has a nontrivial solution, as the rank of the matrix indicates).